# Can not able to read data from custom AXI peripheral register

Tags: c, fpga, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I am working with a Zynq board where a custom AXI 4 lite slave peripheral is created and then added from the IP Repository.
And created a synthesizable custom IP in vivado (**which is sine wave IP**)and also wrote a C code for reading this IP output ( i want to read a data from the register). But somehow it shows something diff. instead of what I expect.

Here I'm attaching a screenshot and my c code for that. 
But in teraterm it shows some garbage memory state.
**Here, I'm expecting a sinewave output. ( In digit form )**
Pls, **suggest me correction or suggestion** about Where could I have gone wrong or what have I missed in C code?.

[image]

```
#include "xil_printf.h"
#include "xil_io.h"
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xil_types.h"
#include "xparameters_ps.h"


#include <stdio.h>
//Definitions for peripheral  MYIPINETHREE_0 //
#define XPAR_ MYIPINETHREE_0_DEVICE_ID 0
#define XPAR_ MYIPINETHREE_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR 0x43C00000
#define XPAR_ MYIPINETHREE_0_S00_AXI_HIGHADDR 0x43C0FFFF

int main(){
    u32 baseaddr;
    int sine, sinephase, enable,reg ;
    while (1)
    {
    xil_printf("start of ip test\r");

    if (enable == 1)
                    reg = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        else
                reg = 0x00000000;
     Xil_Out32(0x43C00000, 32 );
sine = Xil_In32(baseaddr+4);

    xil_printf("\r state: %d", sine);
     Xil_Out32(0x43C00000, 32);
     sinephase = Xil_In32(baseaddr+4);
        xil_printf("\r state: %d", sinephase);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To start with: you never initialize `baseaddr` but use it to read from.

Also I can't say because I have no idea how to verify that your addresses are correct. Normally you should use the defines from your xparameters.h file where the Xilinx board package program puts them. I don't see that happening here.

<sub>I am somewhat suspicious as all my Xilinx AXI addresses start with 0x800... but then I might be because I am using a different FPGA.</sub>

Comment: Just as an information: The address space depends on the AXI Master you are using. You can see the address layout when you take a look at the address space in the [reference manual](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf). So the address space 0x40000000 is normal for AXI master 0.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a board layout or some additional information. You should use the addresses from `xparameters.h`instead of hard coding them into your source code. The address space depends on your AXI master interface.